# SQL Server normalizing for performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop

I have a table

```
create table Objects (
    ObjectID bigint not null primary key,
    ObjectRef1 varchar(50) not null,
    ObjectRef2 varchar(50) not null,
    ObjectRef3 varchar(250) not null 
)
```

All fields are unique. The table has approximately 100 million rows. All columns have unique indexes, and are used frequently for queries.

What is faster? To normalize each of the varchar fields into seperate tables, or keep them as they are? If normalized, the table will only have the ObjectID column and ID's to the normalized tables, and I would do inner joins to get the values of ObjectRefX.

Should I consider other databases like Hadoop for this amount of data?

Comment: This is probably on-topic here, but you're more likely to receive a useful answer over at Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing about performance is on cannot predict until and unless query runs, I would suggest you to please keep the table as it is, as normalizing this data in different table would increase the dependency as you will be connecting the table with foreign keys. and more over all the columns are unique so there is no redundancy that could be reduced. Place indexes . and try to optimize the query rather then the schema here .

any correction to above answer is welcome.

hope I could be of any help

Thanks

Ashutosh Arya